# Why does php migration keeps on creating columns on default cashier model (User) even changed to different model

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I would like to change the default cashier's model to my custom model (Users to Companies)

What i have done is

1. changed the services.php's model to App\Models\Companies\Companies::class
2. changed my .env's to CASHIER_MODEL=App\Models\Companies\Companies
3. published the cashier migration and alter the table name to companies but

php artisan migrate will  still update cashier's default model that is Users

```
// services.php
    'stripe' => [
            'model' => App\Models\Companies\Companies::class,
            'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
            'webhook' => [
                'secret' => env('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET'),
                'tolerance' => env('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_TOLERANCE', 300),
            ],
        ],

CASHIER_MODEL=App\Models\Companies\Companies  // on .env


// on migration
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable()->collation('utf8mb4_bin')->index();
            $table->string('card_brand')->nullable();
            $table->string('card_last_four', 4)->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Cancel the artisan serve and run composer dump-autoload and run php artisan serve again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel keeps loading the Cashier migrations from the vendor folder even if you have published them to the database/migrations folder and edited them.

The solution is to explicitly tell Laravel to ignore the vendor migrations.

Add the following to the register method of the AppServiceProvider:

```
// Use the Cashier migrations from migration folder instead of vendor folder
Cashier::ignoreMigrations();
```

Remember to also include:

```
use Laravel\Cashier\Cashier;
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would consider this a Laravel Cashier bug. The default Laravel Cashier migrations should create the subscriptions table joining the to Cashier model you define in the Cashier config and it should only add the Cashier columns to that Model. At any rate, here's the full workaround.

1. Disable the default Laravel Cashier Migrations in `AppServiceProvider.php` by adding `Cashier::ignoreMigrations();` to the `register()` method.

   ```
   namespace App\Providers;

   use Laravel\Cashier\Cashier;
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
       /**
        * Bootstrap any application services.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function boot()
       {
           //
       }

       /**
        * Register any application services.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function register()
       {
           Cashier::ignoreMigrations();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create the following migrations: `php artisan make:migration create_subscriptions_table` and `php artisan make:migration create_customer_columns`
3. Copy the migration content from the migrations in `vendor/laravel/cashier/database/migrations/` into your newly created migration files.
4. Replace any reference to `users` and `user_id` with the Laravel Cashier model you have decided to use.